# The movie created_at the same day of today but X years ago

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I was using this system to have a list of the movies created the say day/month but not toda(=this year).

```
scope :anniversary, -> {
  where(
    'DATE(created_at) = ?', 
    (1..9).collect{|year| year.years.ago.to_date}
  )
}
```

But I have this error

**PG: DatatypeMismatch: ERROR: argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type record
LINE 1: SELECT "movies".* FROM "movies" WHERE (DATE(created_at) = '20...
: SELECT "movies".* FROM "movies" WHERE (DATE(created_at) = '2020-02-13', '2019-02-13', '2018-02-13') ORDER BY  random() LIMIT $1**

Any idea about how to fix?

Can I edit this part `(1..9).collect` with something to exclude just the current year? (to don't update the script every year)

Answer (score 1):

There's an easy fix to that. If you want to add a where statement in which something is *this or that or that*, then you put *this or that or that* in an array and change `= ?` to `IN (?)`. In your example, this looks like:

```
where('DATE(created_at) IN (?)', (1..9).collect{|year| year.years.ago.to_date}
```

Comment: How can I edit this part (1..9).collect with something to exclude just the present year? (to don't update the script every year)

Comment: You might have to do a 2nd query first. I'm thinking you get the oldest movie with `Movie.order('created_at DESC').last`, get the number of years between that date and `Date.today` and then use that instead of the 9.

Comment: I solvedi with where('DATE(created_at) IN (?)', (1..(Time.now.year - first.created_at.year)).collect{|year| year.years.ago.to_date})

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Postgres database try using this query

```
Modal.where('extract(year from created_at) <> ? AND extract(month  from created_at) = ? AND extract(day  from created_at) = ?', Time.current.year, Time.current.month, Time.current.day)
```

Comment: It works. Is it faster/better than where('DATE(created_at) IN (?)', (1..(Time.now.year - first.created_at.year)).collect{|year| year.years.ago.to_date})